# URL Rewritng is working but auto redirect is not for my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used URL rewriting with .htaccess with the below code. Problem is that if we paste the URL then it's working but auto redirection is not working.

**.HTACCESS CODE:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule Sports-Equipment-Catname-(.*)\.html$ Sports-Equipment.php?Catname=$1
```

**My URLS:**

```
http://example.com/Sports-Equipment.php?Catname=Discus
```

**If I paste direct URL from htaccess is:**

```
http://example.com/Sports-Equipment-Catname-Discus.html
```

why URLs is not auto-redirected to new pages.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Well, you have no redirection rule in your configuration. So it is not surprising that no redirection is performed.

Comment: @arkascha can u help me to fixed it.

Comment: I think it makes sense to first establish what it actually is you want to achieve... Is it _really_ a redirection you want to get applied? Why? That makes little sense in my eyes. Or is this a confusion of words? I'd say you should describe what you want to achieve instead of _how_ you want to achieve it ...

Answer (score 0):

> why URLs is not auto-redirected to new pages.

There is no "automatic" process here. You have no directives that implement the redirect.

> My URLs: `/Sports-Equipment.php?Catname=Discus`

That's the problem, you need to change the actual URLs in your HTML source. This should not be resolved with a "redirect". Otherwise, the user can still "see" the old URL before they click the link. If they copy a link they are copying the "old" URL. Every time the user clicks a link they are redirected - which is slow, not just for the user, but also for your server (uses more resources).

However, you should implement a redirect if you are *changing* an existing URL structure. But this is to preserve SEO only. For search engines that have indexed the old URLs and for third party backlinks to the old URLs.

For that you would need to add the following "redirect" *before* the existing rewrites. For example:

```
# Redirect "old" URL to "new" URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Catname=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^Sports-Equipment\.php$ /Sports-Equipment-Catname-%1.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures we only redirect direct requests and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite - thus avoiding a redirect loop.

The `QSD` flag discards the query string from the initial request.

Comment: MrWhite, thanks you for great help. This is now auto redirected but now my pages are not working. They are showing 4O4 error page. 

Do you have any suggestion how to fixed its.

Comment: @VinexSports I assumed your URLs (eg. `http://example.com/Sports-Equipment-Catname-Discus.html`) were working using the directive in your question?